# how can i see a calendar using a c program??

Tags: c

suppose a date 12/12/1988 is given to you. write a c program that will display the calendar of that particular month.

Comment: is this homework? if so, you should add the `homework` tag.

Comment: At the risk of giving away a homework assignment, see: http://c.snippets.org/snip_lister.php?fname=cal.c

Answer (score 4):

The program "cal" is probably a good example.

```
$ cal
       February 2011
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
       1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28
```

The above was shown using a Mac OS X 10.6 system, however, almost every unix or unix-like (including linux) will likely have it.

It is described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cal_(Unix)

As it happens, "cal" *is* a C program, the source code for the freeBSD version (probably the authoritative version) is at http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/usr.bin/ncal/

Comment: @alfesani: Care to refine your question? As it stands, I have given you a practical, real example of how it would be shown in a C program. You might wish to port it to windows if this program is exactly what you are after? I don't see anything inherently non-portable in the ncal code.

Comment: Sir, the output you have shown exactly matches what i want to display. i just want to know that is there any inbuilt function that could display such when we call that function. pls help me

Comment: @alfesani: No, not in standard C.  Any such functionality will need to be implemented by the programmer. This is, infact, exactly what is shown here.  The ncal source code shows the implementation, in C, of such a program that displays the output. You are free to port that to windows if you choose, or write your own.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find the code for printing calender in C:
[How-to-make-a-calender-in-c](http://www.codingunit.com/how-to-make-a-calendar-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to use

```
  system("cal 12 1988");
```

but I bet that isn't what your instructor is looking for,

Comment: Sir, I have run this code in TC compiler bt its not giving the output. pls help me

Comment: @alfesani: You might need to install a copy of the 'cal' program...

Answer (score 1):

This is more than what you need. Go though the code and it will help you.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/c-cpp-calender/